# How can I detect an object in the game and send virtual click to it with Python?

Tags: python, opencv, sendmessage

Let there be an apple in the game. I want to send a virtual click on that apple to detect the apple in the game and take my character to where the apple is. What resources should I check?

Comment: Which game? You are making the game?

Comment: For Metin2 game.

Answer (score 2):

You can use OpenCV for it.

Capture the Minecraft window from your desktop and then use cascade classifier or mask operations to detect a stone and then send a virtual click. Because all of these processes are not basic lines of code, I cannot write them down here. Instead, I will be sharing an example project for you to check out.

[Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUU6ZsJlZKQ&t=1343s)

Answer (score 0):

Sending mouse/keyboard input can by done in python using [**pyautogui**][1] module. 
*Once back in time I wanted to create a simple clicker detecting orange squares in game, and done some research and I found out that*:

- If you don't have some kind of API you can't just detect UI element
- You can do that simply, by screenshoting every few seconds, and using hardcode image detection to find orange square.
- Assuming you want to do it in minecraft, it won't be easy unless you use sth like Fabric API (it wild be muuuuuch easier, but you need to know js)
- You can make screenshoot+simple AI combo to find stone :)
  Hope this will answer your question.

Comment: As far as I know, we can send virtual clicks with win32gui.SendMessage module. What I want is to combine it with opencv.

Comment: Good luck with your project. Tell how it went. I didn’t knew about this metod.